# Best way to write to Network share

Tags: c#, asp.net, networking, share

I have a C# web app that needs to be able to read and write to a Network share folder. I can do this writing a file to C:\temp folder if folder has modify rights for the, "Network Service" user. However, it throws an error

> System Unauthorized Access Exception: Access to the path UNC Path\filename is denied.

when I attempt to use the UNC name to write the same file to Network folder. This occurs even though folder has Network service with modify rights. There are numerous solutions on this, but I was wondering what the best strategy to employ would be.

Comment: Best strategy is the one that matches your security requirements. No one except you can make that decision.

Comment: Side note: please don't [add tags to title](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253028/why-is-removing-tags-from-the-title-suggested-so-often) and [thank you notes to post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267384/removing-someone-elses-thank-you).

Comment: Is there a preferred method to implement this for a low-security app? Impersonation, specific user to app pool etc? Just looking for a little guidance.

Comment: Id recommend using a specific application pool, whose domain identity has the correct rights to run the web application. Its what I've used in the past to grant network resource rights to a web application.

Comment: Based on your post - "There are numerous solutions on this" - you already found multiple solutions - now it is up to you to decide which one to pick. If you want this answer be reasonable for SO - make sure to provide criteria for "better" in your case and highlight issues with existing solutions you've tried.